# How do you exclude files from a search using a file list

Tags: bash

I am building a “m3u” playlist using an iterative bash script.  Once the m3u file has tracks listed in it, how do I use that file as a filter to exclude existing tracks when appending?

As you may already know, an m3u playlist is simply a list of file pointers.

For example, let's say you have "myplaylist.m3u" with these songs in it:

```
/path/a_fine_frenzy/bomb_in_a_birdcage/06_-_a_fine_frenzy_-_swan_song.mp3
/path/a_fine_frenzy/one_cell_in_the_sea/06_-_a_fine_frenzy_-_almost_lover.mp3
/path/a_fine_frenzy/bomb_in_a_birdcage/07_-_a_fine_frenzy_-_elements.mp3
/path/a_fine_frenzy/one_cell_in_the_sea/07_-_a_fine_frenzy_-_think_of_you.mp3
```

You now want to continue appending "myplaylist.m3u" with a different search that might include the above songs, but you do not want them added again. So how do you exclude the files listed in future searches?

Your search might normally be something like:

```
find /home/username/Music/ -type f -iname "*.mp3" >> myplaylist.m3u
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter the results of `find` before appending, using `grep`:

```
find /home/username/Music/ -type f -iname "*.mp3" | grep -vxf myplaylist.m3u >> myplaylist.m3u
```

Explanation of the flags:

- `-f file` use patterns from `file`
- `-x` match entire lines
- `-v` invert the logic: print lines that don't match, instead of lines that match

As a result, `grep` will output only lines of `find` that are not yet in the file.

Comment: Different (but related to using -f) question: what if you have an "exclude list" file and just want to use that file to exclude the results of a general search, then what grep switches work for: find /home/username/Music/ -type f -iname "*.mp3" | grep -??? excluded_file > search_minus_excludes

Comment: The same flags. If you think about it, `myplaylist.m3u` is practically an exclude list too. Add another `grep` command in the pipeline with the same flags.

Comment: Yes, please.  Using /home/username/Music/a_fine_frenzy/ -type f -iname "*.mp3" | grep -vxf out2.m3u | grep -vxf revised.m3u where "out2.m3u" contains the files to exclude, revised.m3u still includes the files from out2.csv.

Comment: @user3447273 `find /home/username/Music/a_fine_frenzy/ -type f -iname "*.mp3" | grep -vxf out2.m3u | grep -vxf revised.m3u > search_minus_excludes` -- as the result, `search_minus_excludes` will not include the files in `out2.m3u` and in `revised.m3u`

Comment: That command did not exclude the two files in 'out2.m3u' from the resulting file 'search_minus_excludes'.  Note the file 'revised.m3u' was empty after running this.

Comment: Are you saying that `revised.m3u` was not empty before running this and became empty after running this? That cannot be caused by this command, there's nothing in it to modify `revised.m3u`. Note that files will be excluded only if they match perfectly, because of the `-x` flag. Are you sure the lines in `out2.m3u` match perfectly? For example, if the input has a line like `/file1.mp3` and `out2.m3u` has a line like `file1.mp3`, that's not a perfect match, so `/file1.mp3` will not be excluded. Please clarify.

Comment: Yes, the files matched exactly. Let's say you have five files, a.tst, b.tst, c.tst, d.tst and e.tst. A database tracks certain information not contained in those files, but you can export a file called exclude.lst, with the names of files to be excluded. Let's say this month two files are listed: b.tst and d.tst (but it could change from time to time).

Do a general file search for *.tst files on a parent directory and its children, but exclude the files shown in exclude.lst, then output the resulting list to a file called output_less_excludes.lst.

Comment: These comments are really for a different question, so I will ask that separately (and hopefully more clearly).

Comment: Ok, this syntax works: find /home/username/test/ -type f -iname "*.tst" | grep -vxf exclude.lst > output_less_excludes.lst for the example problem I wrote in these comments.  Thanks for your help Janos!